# Using Laravel RESTfull with namespacing

Tags: php, laravel, controller, namespaces

I have a problem. I am building an administration panel for my application and decided, because of the many functions, to use a RESTfull route. Now, because I do not want to jam every function in the same class I also use namespacing and extend my AdminController class.

The problem is, RESTFull works for the functions declared in the AdminController file, but it does not recognize the functions deeper within the namespace. What is the correct way to do this?

This is the code I have right now:

**RESTfull Route**

```
Route::controller('admin', 'Admin\AdminController');
```

**AdminController (/controllers/AdminController.php)**

```
namespace Admin;
use View;

class AdminController extends \BaseController {

public function getSales() {
     echo"Works";
}
```

**DashboardController (/controllers/admin/DashboardController.php**

```
namespace Admin;

use AdminController;
use View;

class DashboardController extends AdminController {

public function getDashboard() {
     echo"Does not work";
}
```

I can access www.domain.com/admin/sales just fine, but when I access www.domain.com/admin/dashboard it gives me a "Controller method not found" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should provide this route manually:

```
Route::controller('admin/dashboard', 'Admin\DashboardController');
```

In your code Laravel has no idea that it should use `DashboardController` and not `AdminController` for `admin/dashboard` route